# Trigger if form has change. Django

Tags: django

I have a trouble working on a ticketing system. Users create a ticket and get the information sent to their email. How can I send new information when a ticket gets changed from the admin panel?

model:

```
class TroubleTicket(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(choices=ADDRESSES, default=None,  
    max_length=200)
    room = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    message = RichTextUploadingField()
    state = models.CharField(choices=STATES, max_length=30,   
    default='New')
    answer = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('ticket_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.id})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-create_date']
```

save form and sending a message if the user specified a mail:

```
class CreateTicket(CreateView):
    template_name = 'incidentjournal/add_ticket.html'

    form_class = TicketForm
    model = TroubleTicket
    context_object_name = 'ticket'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        recipient = form.cleaned_data['email'].encode('utf8')
        new_ticket = form.save()
        new_ticket_id = new_ticket.pk
        address = new_ticket.address.encode('utf8')
        title = new_ticket.title.encode('utf8')
        name = new_ticket.name.encode('utf8')
        room = new_ticket.room.encode('utf8')

        send_to_email(recipient, str(new_ticket_id), title, address,  
        room, name)

        send_to_bot(str(new_ticket_id), title, address, room, name)

        return super(CreateTicket, self, ).form_valid(form)
```

If the state or the answer has been changed in the admin panel I want to send the changes to the user.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: if `state` changes means if a that particular ticket has been updated right? So why don't you use an UpdateView to send the email whenever there is a change. Have you tried something like that?

Comment: Take a look at the [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/) documentation. That should provide a solution.